# Why would I get different answers for using different methods in calculating the volume formed by revolution?

Tags: calculus

I want to calculate the volume of solid formed by rotating the region R bounded by $$ y=1+\sqrt{x} ,x=0,x=9, y=0$$ about x-axis.

So, using disk-washer methods:
$$ \pi\int_0^9 (1+\sqrt{x})^2 dx= \frac{171}{2}\pi $$
while using cylindrical shell method:
$$2\pi\int_1^4 y(9-(y-1)^2)dy$$
which would yield a different answer. May I ask why?

Comment: Your $R$ region is not well defined. You need to add some boundary like $y=0$ or $y=4$.

Comment: Sorry, the boundary is y=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add $$2\pi \int_0^1 y\cdot 9 \, dy$$ to second integral.

Comment: May I ask why do I need to add that? Thx so much

Comment: Your second integral does not take into account part of rotation figure that has $y$ from 0 to 1.

Comment: I see, thx so much. Is there any direct way that I can use the shell method to calculate the volume. I tried $$\int_0^4 y(9-(y-1)^2) dy $$ to try to take into account that missing figure, but still failed.

Comment: For $0<y<1$ region $R$ is bounded with $x=0$ and $x=9$ so $\Delta x=9$. For $1 < y <4$ region $R$ is bounded with $x=(y-1)^2$ and $x=9$ so $\Delta x=9-(y-1)^2$ as in your second integral.

Comment: You can use shell method but as formulae are different for $y<1$ and $y>1$ you should split integral in two parts.

Comment: thx so much for your helpk

Answer (score 1):

This would have been a comment under the accepted answer, but it's too long.

It looks like you may have gotten the idea already by now, but in case it helps:

[The answer you accepted](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4366584/139123) **is** the direct way of solving via shells, which is that you must look at your entire region and find all the shells before you set up any integrals. This will tell you right away that you have to integrate from $0$ to $4.$

If you had a convenient function $h(y)$ such that $h(y)=9$ when $0<y<9$ and $h(y)=9-(y-1)^2$ and you knew how to integrate that function in a single integral,
$$ \int_0^4 y\cdot h(y)\,\mathrm dy,$$
you could just do that. But the function $h$ is defined in such a way that none of our usual methods for solving an integral can find an antiderivative that is good over the entire interval $0<y<4,$ so we break the interval $[0,4]$ into pieces such that we **do** know how to find an antiderivative within each piece and can integrate piecewise,

$$ \int_0^4 y\cdot h(y)\,\mathrm dy
 = \int_0^1 y\cdot h(y)\,\mathrm dy + \int_1^4 y\cdot h(y)\,\mathrm dy.$$

Just remember in future that the bounds of the integral come from the entire shape given in the problem statement and not just from one part of the boundary
and you should be much better prepared to get the right answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed reply, it really helps.